# Determine the functions of the given multiplexers

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, multiplexer, boolean-algebra

In the following problem I want to understand a section of the overall problem. The image only show 2 `MUX(es)`, however the original question has a lot more that are connected with one another.

> Write the outputs for the following diagram only in terms of the relevant multiplexer inputs.

[image]

The first one is relatively simple because I use the same idea as for a normal `2:1 MUX`. So for `r` I get `r = (not a*0) + (a*1) = a`. The value of `r` is then forwarded to two other `MUX(es)`. For one of the given MUX(es) I have `t=(not c*r) + (c*0) = (not c*r)`. Is this correct? I'm not a 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, seems correct. Using typical Verilog or C language notation, we get:

- r = ~a & 0 | a & 1

which reduces to:

- r = a

Then:

- t = ~c & r | c & 0

Which reduces to:

- t = ~c & r

And ultimately, since we know r = a:

- t = ~c & a